# Android Two-way Data Binding Using MutableStateFlow and Observe Changes in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-databinding, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

Just learned `MutableStateFlow`, trying to replace `MutableLiveData`. Also **Android** doesn't recommend that we observe `LiveData` inside `ViewModel` (unless you use `observeForever(observer)` but you need to remember to remove it so it's kind of troublesome).

```
data class Student(var id: Long, var name: String, var countryIndex: Int)

class FirstViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val uiScope = viewModelScope               //Main Dispatcher

    val countries = listOf("China", "America", "Japan", "Korea")
    val student = Student(0, "Kate", 2)        //faking database object  

    val country = MutableStateFlow(countries[student.countryIndex])    //two-way bind with AutoCompleteTextView "text" attribute

    init {
        observeCountry()
    }

    private fun observeCountry() = uiScope.launch {        //<- should move to other Dispatcher??
        country.collect { country ->
            countries.indexOf(country).let { student.countryIndex = it }    //country name -> country index -> update Student object
        }
    }
}
```

Above code works perfectly fine, but I want to make sure that whether I use `MutableStateFlow` properly in this example. Do I need to switch to `Dispatchers.Default` for the `collect{}`?

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#lifecycle-objects) points out it should look like this:

```
private val _country = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>("")
val country: StateFlow<List<String>> = _country
```

where `_country` you use for update value and `country` to refer for reading to the rest application (to consumers)

The issue is you could not use `StateFlow<>` type for two-way bindings, only for reading. At least I haven't found yet the way to operate it and keep `MutableStateFlow<>` encapsulated.

Just a remark to your code.